# An array of child objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, inheritance

I created a parent class that i named **Courrier**

```
public class Courrier {
private double poid;
private boolean expr;
String ad;
private char z ;
public Courrier(double poid, boolean expr, String ad, char z) {
    this.poid = poid;
    this.expr = expr;
    this.ad = ad;
    this.z = z;
}
public double getPoid() {
    return poid;
}
public boolean isExpr() {
    return expr;
}
public String getAd() {
    return ad;
}
public char getZ() {
    return z;
}}
```

and two children classes both contains a method named `affranchir()`
then there is a class **Test**:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Courrier[] T = new Courrier[4];
    T[0] = new Lettre(200, true, "London", 'C', "A3");
    T[1] = new Colis(3000, false, "Barcelone", 'B', 50);
    T[2] = new Lettre(500, false, "Béchar", 'A', "A4");
    T[3] = new Colis(150, true, "New york", 'C', 175);
    double tarif=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(T[i].affranchir());
            tarif+=T[i].affranchir();
    }
    System.out.println(tarif);
}}
```

well there is a problem it says 
The method `affranchir()` is undefined for the type **Courrier**
and i want to make it work without casting is there any possible way please ?

Comment: Implement the method in the base class (and the child classes `@Override` it) - otherwise no (I'm not counting reflection as a better solution to casting)

Comment: Java decides which method are accessible based on reference type, not on actual type. If you want to be able to access `affranchir()` method via your superclass reference then that type needs to have that method. But maybe you don't really need your array to be of your superclass? Maybe you can create separate `interface` which will contain methods you want to invoke, then make your subclasses implement that interface? This way you can have `YourInterface[]` array instead of `Courrier[]` array which can hold all instances which implement that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an abstract method to courrier

```
public abstract class Courrier {

/* code */

 public abstract void affranchir();

/* code */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made an array of parent class Courrier

```
 Courrier[] T = new Courrier[4];
```

and then you are calling a method of child class by that Object

```
T[i].affranchir();
```

This is the only error. Instead of making Object of parent class make Object of the child class and then call that method. It will definitely work.
Thank You

Comment: i know 
but i was told to make an array of parent class Courrier
thnxx

Comment: If you want to make array of parent class then define the method
affranchir() in parent class itself.